# MVC 3 Validation Attribute Error Message for Multi Tenant Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on Multi Tenant application using MVC3 and C#.
I am using model class with properties decorated with validation attributes.
What I want to do is to return tenant specific error messages on the client side and on the server side as well.

Is there any way to hook mvc validation and render / return tenant specific messages per each request in runtime?

My code snippet is very sipmle:

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="errormessage",        ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Global)]
  [RegularExpression(@"\d+", ErrorMessageResourceName="errormessagedigit",   ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Global)]  
  public string TestProperty {get; set;}
}
```

View:

```
@using(Html.BeginFrom())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "")<br/> 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TextProperty)<br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a set of [custom validation attributes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC-3) that each inherit from one of the existing validation attributes (e.g. `MyRequired`), but include code to inject the tenant specific error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure out the answer to my question.

You need to inherit from each existing attribute and override FormatErrorMessage method.
In this method you can access ErrorMessageString property which contains original validation attribute error message. You can create request / tenant specific  logic to format /override error message.

Looks like this approach can return /render custom per each request  error message.

Code snippet:

```
public class RequiredAttributeTest:RequiredAttribute   
 {

public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)        
   {
        // code to return request / tenant specific error message    
        return GetTenantError(ErrorMessageString, name); 
    }
}

public class RegularExpressionAtributeTest:RegularExpressionAttribute
  {
    public RegularExpressionAtributeTest(string pattern) : base(pattern) { }

public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {           
       // code to return request / tenant specific error message     
        return GetTenantError(ErrorMessageString, name);
    }
  }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
…
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredAttributeTest),  typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter
(typeof(RegularExpressionAtributeTest), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
…
}
```